# How to config so that the Server can see the image location of GWT app when the app was not put into ROOT folder of Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, gwt

Ok, I built an GWT app. It has `images` folder located inside `war` folder.

In my UiBinder I have something likje this

```
 <g:Image url="/images/oLogo.png"/>
```

I compiled my project and bring all the compiled files into Root folder of tomcat then all imagea are fine as I can see them

But if I copy the compiled files into a folder that is not Root folder like ABC, then i can not see the image though the app works fine. This time the image location will be  `ABC/images`

I do not want to change  `ABC/images/..` for all the image url in my Gwt app, then the question is `how to config the server so that i can see my images?`

Comment: `images/oLogo.png` without the first slash should work, because it's relative rather than absolute.

Comment: but at the client side, do u know the code "http://"+Window.Location.getHost()+ "/"+"images/.." work in eclipse, but not work in server because we got the folder ABC , so can we identify the folder between image & Location.getHost() at client side?